# Hazelcast detection of crashed nodes

Tags: java, concurrency, hazelcast

Here is my simplified use case:

- I have two embedded nodes, each running in its own JVM, on a same physical machine. I start them and they form a simple cluster.
- both nodes try to acquire the same lock
- first one to acquire the lock keeps it for 30 seconds
- If I kill the node that holds the lock, it takes anything between 5 and 10 seconds for the cluster to conclude that the node is dead and to free the lock

My question is: can this interval between killing the node that keeps the lock and cluster actually freeing the lock be shortened? I need it to be less than 1 second.

I tried some of the available properties, that seemed to be related to this problem:

```
hazelcast.socket.connect.timeout.seconds
hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout
hazelcast.client.invocation.timeout.seconds
```

None of it helped, I noticed no change in the behavior of the lock.

**Update:**

Seems these two are the right ones to use:

```
<property name="hazelcast.socket.connect.timeout.seconds">1</property>
<property name="hazelcast.connection.monitor.max.faults">1</property>
```

I have yet to see whether it will cause stability issues in the real usage scenario. In this simple test it works quite well.